# Detect if a user has created a 4x4 line in a 4x4 grid of divs

Tags: vue.js

So I am building my own custom bingo table that is `4x4` with vue. I have everything down except how to detect wether a user has formed a 4x4 line that is horizontal, diagonal, or vertical

[image]

Inside my data function I have an array that represents the 4x4

```
[9, 13, 28, 24],
[11, 22, 15, 43],
[54, 5, 37, 4],
[27, 40, 12, 36]
```

My question is how can I check to see if a user has clicked a 4x4 line? No code is needed as an answer I just want to know how I can approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an `n x n` matrix

**Horizontal:**

Are there `n` selected elements that have the same `rowIndex`?

**Vertical:**

Are there `n` selected elements that have the same `columnIndex`?

**Diagonal (Top Left to Bottom Right)**

Are there `n` elements that have the same `rowIndex` as their `columnIndex`?

**Diagonal (Top Right to Bottom Left)**

Are there `n` elements that satisfy `(length(row) - 1) - rowIndex  == columnIndex`?

```js
const Card = Vue.component('card', {
  template: '#card',
  props: {
    playerCard: Array
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedVals: [],
      rowCounts: {},
      colCounts: {}
    }
  },
  computed: {
    horizontalNumberToWin() {
      return this.playerCard[0].length;
    },
    verticalNumberToWin() {
      return this.playerCard.length;
    },
    diagonalNumberToWin() {
      return this.playerCard.length;
    },
    isDiagonal() {
      if (this.selectedVals.length < this.diagonalNumberToWin) return false;
      // top left to bottom right
      // [0, 0] [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], etc..
      const isTLtoBR = this.selectedVals.filter(val => val[0] === val[1]);
      if (isTLtoBR.length >= this.diagonalNumberToWin) return true;

      // top right to bottom left
      // [0, 3], [1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 0], etc..
      const rowLen = this.playerCard[0].length;
      const isTRtoBL = this.selectedVals.filter(val => {
        return (rowLen -1) - val[0] === val[1];
      });      
      if (isTRtoBL.length >= this.diagonalNumberToWin) return true;

      return false;
    },
    isHorizontal() {
      if (this.selectedVals.length < this.horizontalNumberToWin) return false;
      return Object.values(this.rowCounts).some(row => row >= this.horizontalNumberToWin);
    },
    isVertical() {
      if (this.selectedVals.length < this.verticalNumberToWin) return false;
      return Object.values(this.colCounts).some(col => col >= this.verticalNumberToWin);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onCardClicked(coord) {
      this.selectedVals.push(coord);
      this.updateCounts(coord);
    },
    cardDisabled(coord) {
      return this.selectedVals.some(vals => vals[0] === coord[0] && vals[1] === coord[1]);
    },
    updateCounts(coord) {
      const rowIndex = coord[0];
      const colIndex = coord[1];
      this.rowCounts[rowIndex] = this.rowCounts[rowIndex] ? this.rowCounts[rowIndex] + 1 : 1;
      this.colCounts[colIndex] = this.colCounts[colIndex] ? this.colCounts[colIndex] + 1 : 1;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Card,
  },
  data: {
    playerCard: [
      [9, 13, 28, 24],
      [11, 22, 15, 43],
      [54, 5, 37, 4],
      [27, 40, 12, 36]
    ],
  },
})
```

```css
#app { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.board {
  max-width: 500px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <card :player-card="playerCard" />
</div>

<template id="card">
  <div>
    <p>Horizontal: {{ isHorizontal }}</p>
    <p>Vertical: {{ isVertical }}</p>
    <p>Diagonal: {{ isDiagonal }}</p>
    <div class="board">
      <template v-for="(row, rowIndex) in playerCard">
        <button
          v-for="(col, colIndex) in row"
          :key="col"
          :disabled="cardDisabled([rowIndex, colIndex])"
          @click="onCardClicked([rowIndex, colIndex])">
          {{ col }}
        </button>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should add `isClick` to check whether the user has clicked the card or not.

```
[
  [
    { Number: 9 , isClick: false },
    { Number: 13 , isClick: false },
    { Number: 28 , isClick: false },
    { Number: 24 , isClick: false }
  ],
  // other array ...
]
```

Second, bind your data into html (Maybe you should used twice v-for to achieve it). When user click the card, set `isClick = true`.

Third, write your own logic to check if a user has clicked a 4x4 line.